# Redirecting to different website from any path in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have edited my .htaccess file (probably incorrectly) and when anyone visits a particular subdirectory in the url path I want to redirect them.

This is true for if they visit `/support/` or `/support/something-else` or even `/support/v1/something`

```
Redirect 301 /support https://new-domain.com/support/

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywebsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mywebsite/index.php [L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/support/(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/support/$1

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: First of all, you are not supposed to mess with anything between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comments - WordPress might _overwrite_ that part of the .htaccess, when you flush your permalinks. Whatever you add, needs to be placed outside.

Comment: Second, you don’t need to use RedirectMatch here - `Redirect` by itself does _prefix_-based matching already, and appends any excess to the target URL automatically. `Redirect 301 /support/ https://new-domain.com/support/` should do the job here - try and place that before all the WP rewriting stuff.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for your answer. I have updated my question as you suggested, obviously using the actual domain I want to redirect to in my actual code but I just get a 404 error saying the page is not found.

Comment: 404 from where - the old domain, or the new one?

Comment: @CBroe, based on the example htacess in my question, I am going to `mywebsite.com/support` which should redirect me to `https://new-domain.com/support` but is giving me a 404 error on `mywebsite.com`

Comment: And is that the WordPress 404 page, or just whatever default error document is configured on your server?

Comment: It is the 404 wordpress page that I set up in wordpress ie: 404.php

Comment: I can’t say for sure in what order the directives are evaluated, when mod_rewrite and mod_alias functionality are mixed like this. Try and use the rewrite engine for this part as well. Try `RewriteEngine On [newline] RewriteRule ^support/(.*) https://new-domain.com/support/$1 [R=301]` placed at the very top instead.

Comment: Hmm. still no joy. Maybe I am going to have to resort to a plugin for this. Would have preferred not to use a plugin though.

Comment: Did you try to put the `.htaccess` file in the `support` directory?